# How SQUISH automation tool is better than APPIUM?

Tags: appium, squish

how to choose between these two automation tool how Squish is better tool

Answer (score 2):

These tools are simply different and its up to you to decide which suites better your needs & budget:

**Appium**

- open-sourced and it costs nothing.
- no support engineers to help you with developing tests and telling how to use Appium in a better way. Its only you to search information in docs and forum, ask questions and spend your own time.
- no test recorder, you can simulate similar actions and test locators with [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop), but thats it
- requires knowledge of at least 1 programming language (java, python, js, ruby, etc.) to write the tests.

**SQUISH**

- proprietary software with individual licence costing ~7k EUR a year
- you can contact support engineers, you already paying for it.
- test recorder will help in case you are not familiar with programming

In terms of stability & easy to use it more person & application specific, so I would say: check the points above and made your choice.